# count the number of characters in C

Tags: c, file, count, char, numbers

I need just to count the number of chars in my 'f' file. When I count a number of chars in one string, I get the real number of it, but when I press 'enter' in my .txt and creating a new line I lose 2 chars. So, having 4 strings with 15 chars at all,my program telling me that there are only 9 chars in the file. Help me please to, just, count this unfortunate chars...
Here is a code in C:

```
while (!feof(f)) {
    bool space = 1; //remembering last char (was it space or not)
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) { //running till the end of string
        if (a[i] == ' ') {space = 1;} 
        else if (a[i] != '\0' && a[i] != '\n') {
            chars++;
            if (space == 1) {
                words++; //and counting the words
                space = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: are `chars` and `words` initialized to 0?

Comment: I suggest you refrain from using obscene language in SO posts. Edited it for now.

Comment: I never see you get someting from `f`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Never ever write `while (!feof(f))`. It's always wrong.

Comment: Are you opening in text or binary mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the following would suffice:

```
int c; 
while ((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c=='\n') {
         words++;
    } 
    else {
        chars++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (c=fgetc(f))` doesn't stop at EOF. Shouldn't it be `while ((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF)`?

Comment: and, of course, that doesn't mean, if you count space-chars, you have new words. You should see, if the last char was space and current is not. Then you will have the real number of words;)